# Excel vba - Screen Flickering and screenupdating doesn;t seem to be working

Tags: excel, vba, flicker

I have a field which I update and it then puts in the benchmark information.
However, the screen is flickering.
How do I stop it from flickering?

Code is as follows:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheet3.Range("CJ91") = Benchmark2.Text

Dim myList()
Dim xCount As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim xCell As Range

With Sheets("Choosing Funds").Range("ES2:ES81")
    .AutoFilter 1, "<>"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ReDim myList(1 To rng.Cells.Count)
        For Each xCell In rng
            xCount = xCount + 1
            myList(xCount) = xCell.Text
        Next xCell
    End If
    .AutoFilter
End With

OffshoreFund_List.List = myList

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Completely unrelated.... (maybe), but stop using `On Error Resume Next` immediately. That statement means the code is simply  ***ignoring ***  any and all errors. So finding out if there are any errors occurring is step one.

Comment: Thanks. I took that out. However, the screen is still flickering. Any ideas?

Comment: @AdamMusnitzky,  to expand on what @RubberDuck said, `On Error Resume Next` should **only** be used in cases where you know there will be errors that need to be skipped such as looping through a collection that contains invalid objects (`CommandBars` for example) or when using an external library that can return an unsupported object type and **no where else**.  Learn what errors are possible for each command and handle them correctly.

Comment: Do you have a 'Worksheet_Change' event?

Answer (score 0):

Adam - I see that you've posted this question a couple of times. Now that you have posted this with the actual code, it is much more apparent why you have screen flickering.

When you use .AutoFilter, Excel actually has to add/modify the existing AutoFilter on the source spreadsheet. This is extremely likely to be the cause of the flickering.

It looks like the reason you are using the AutoFilter in this case is because you have a list of values in a source sheet, but you only want to print the values to your OffshoreFund_List where the value in Column E does not equal 1.

If this is the case, then what you should do is actually copy the entire range you want to work with into an array. Now, then create a second array for your results that you will eventually want to print to your OffshoreFund_List. Then, loop through your first array, and for any value that contains a 1 in the fifth column, you can copy over to your target array, ignoring everything else. Then print your results.

Now, your program will still have to interact with the spreadsheet (grabbing the source data and printing the results), but this should not cause the screen flickering.

Let me know if this works.